# PHP - getting gateway timeout error for certain post request on Apache 2

Tags: php, apache, laravel, datatable, timeout

I am running my application on laravel 5.1.27 on server hosted on hostgator. 
Most of the times my POST requests end up in a gateway timeout error. I've restfull APIs which allow user to send POST requests and also I am using datatables. Datatables post request also mostly end up as Timeout Error.

I've read many other threads but can't seem to be successful in removing these Errors. Everything is working fine on my local machine but on server timeout errors occur.

Here are my live server specifications:

[image]

Any help/suggestions would be really appreciated.

Note: I am using shared hosting plan so I don't have root access on my server to solve my problem. So keep this thing in mind while suggesting any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<?php 
    set_time_limit (60); 
?>
```

*Set the number of seconds a script is allowed to run. If this is reached, the script returns a fatal error. The default limit is 30 seconds or, if it exists, the max_execution_time value defined in the php.ini.*

The PHP default is 30 seconds, however your host may set this even lower.

If you change to `60` to `0` this will tell PHP never to time out.
This is not recommended, as if you have a leaky/looping script, this can cause havoc on the server (and your host will probably disable your site until the script stops).

Comment: I'll add it to my top level class' constructor and test it. I'll let you know if it worked.

Comment: You may want to consider using Scheduled Jobs and callback URLs if it takes more than a few seconds to process on your server. I know I wouldn't want to use an API that makes my PHP hang!

Comment: I've added this to my controller file(PHP which handles my request). But still getting gateway timeout error. This request doesn't do much. It receives a POST request of Form Data with some keys containing JSON strings, it processes the request and saves the object to DB. Anything may go wrong in this flow?

Comment: Doesn't sound like it should take long at all. If it's a simple write to the DB, it should be quick. How are you inserting the data? Are there any `do` or `while` or `for` loops that may continuously loop?

Comment: I've some collection as JSON array which contain child objects of concerned node. Just usign `foreach` loop on them. But that should not take long. It was working early morning. This behavior is random. Any POST request starts to give timeout error.